# passing data between JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm making Tetris in Java and would like to have the game play on the left and scoring, buttons, and nextPiece on the right, like so:

[image]

You'll notice that the score on the Game Panel is updating, but the score on the Score Panel (on the right) is not.

On the Game Panel, I have global variables for score and level: `private int level, totalScore;` which are initialized to 0.

and this in my `paint component():`

```
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("Level: " + level, this.getWidth()/2+110, this.getHeight()/2-200);
        g.drawString("Score: " + totalScore, this.getWidth()/2+110, this.getHeight()/2-170);
```

Then I have this code within the Game Panel which calculates level and scoring:

```
public void changeLevel () {
    int max = (level+1)*100;
    if (totalScore >= max) {
        System.out.println(max + "reached... next level");
        level++;
        totalScore = 0;
        timer();
    }
}

public int tallyScore(int totalLines) {
    int score = 0;
    switch (totalLines) {
        case 1: score = 40 * (level + 1);
                break;
        case 2: score = 100 * (level + 1);
                break;
        case 3: score = 300 * (level + 1);
                break;
        case 4: score = 1200 * (level + 1); 
                break;
        default: break;
    }
    return score;
}

//loop through all rows starting at bottom (12 rows)
public void checkBottomFull() {
    int lines = 0;
    for(int row = totalRows-1; row > 0; row--) {
        while (isFull(row)) {       
            lines++;
            clearRow(row);   
        }
    }
    totalScore += tallyScore(lines);    
    //check if level needs to be changed based on current score...
    changeLevel();
    //reset lines after score has been incremented
    lines=0;
}
```

And since I want the Score Panel to display the score, I have these two methods in Game Panel which return the global variables:

```
public int getScore() {
    return totalScore;
}
public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}
```

In my Score Panel `paintComponent()` I have `board.getLevel()` and `board.getScore()` (`board` class is the Game Panel) so I can feed the Game Panel scores to the Score Panel.

```
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("Level: " + board.getLevel(), this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2-130);
    g.drawString("Score: " + board.getScore(), this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2-100);
```

Yet as you can see from the picture, these scores are not updating.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: seems like you make your life harder, than it has to be. instead of messing around with global varables you could use a listener-interface.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an..  Oh why bother?  You ignored me last time.  I'll just vote to close.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I didn't ignore you... I posted the SSCCE but didn't do it quite right... Maybe I don't know how to post an SSCCE even after reading what you linked for me.

Comment: Are you invoking the `paintComponent()` method of your Score Panel from the main game loop?

Comment: No, what I was trying to do was paint two separate panels, so they both have their own `paintComponent()` methods.

Comment: Okay, I was asking if you are updating/painting the Score Panel when you are updating/painting Game Panel. Try to debug your code.

Comment: *"Maybe I don't know how to post an SSCCE"*  An SSCCE related to a run-time problem should ..run.  That code won't even compile.  What is it you do not understand about making it easy for people to help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to separate concerns so that they can be shared. Consider making a class for the logic and data that underlies your GUI, and say you call this class you Model class. Then you can give it a level and a score field and make them "bound properties", meaning that other classes can listen for changes to these fields.  I usually do this by giving my Model a SwingPropertyChangeSupport object and give it an `addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener)` and a `removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener)`, and then I notify all registered PropertyChangeListener's of changes by calling PropertyChangeSupport's fire.  e.g.,

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class Model {
   public static final String SCORE = "score";
   public static final String LEVEL = "level";
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = 
         new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
   private int score;
   private int level;

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public int getScore() {
      return score;
   }

   public void setScore(int score) {
      int oldValue = this.score;
      int newValue = score;

      this.score = score;
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(SCORE, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   public int getLevel() {
      return level;
   }

   public void setLevel(int level) {
      int oldValue = this.level;
      int newValue = level;

      this.level = level;
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(LEVEL, oldValue, newValue);
   }

}
```

Then any GUI or view component that wishes to listen to changes in the values may do so. The below class combines "View" with "Control" if you're studying MVC structure:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class UseModelGui {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Panel1 panel1 = new Panel1();
      Panel2 panel2 = new Panel2();
      Model model = new Model();

      panel1.setModel(model);
      panel2.setModel(model);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("UseModelGui");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class Panel1 extends JPanel {
   private JTextField scoreField = new JTextField(2);
   private JTextField levelField = new JTextField(2);

   public Panel1() {
      scoreField.setFocusable(false);
      scoreField.setEditable(false);
      levelField.setFocusable(false);
      levelField.setEditable(false);

      add(new JLabel("score:"));
      add(scoreField);
      add(new JLabel("Level:"));
      add(levelField);
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Check Values"));
   }

   public void setModel(Model model) {
      model.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
            if (Model.LEVEL.equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
               String level = pcEvt.getNewValue().toString();
               levelField.setText(level);
            } else if (Model.SCORE.equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
               String score = pcEvt.getNewValue().toString();
               scoreField.setText(score);
            }

         }
      });
   }

}

class Panel2 extends JPanel {
   private JSpinner scoreSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0,
         20, 1));
   private JSpinner levelSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0,
         10, 1));
   private Model model;

   public Panel2() {
      add(new JLabel("score:"));
      add(scoreSpinner);
      add(new JLabel("Level:"));
      add(levelSpinner);
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Set Values"));

      scoreSpinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
            int score = ((Integer) scoreSpinner.getValue()).intValue();
            if (model != null) {
               model.setScore(score);
            }
         }
      });
      levelSpinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
            int level = ((Integer) levelSpinner.getValue()).intValue();
            if (model != null) {
               model.setLevel(level);
            }
         }
      });
   }

   public void setModel(Model model) {
      this.model = model;
   }

}
```

The beauty of this is that Panel1 has no knowledge of Panel2, and Model has no knowledge of either. All Panel1 knows of is if Model changes. All Panel2 knows is that it is changing the Model's state. All the Model knows is that its state can change, and its values can be listened to.

You're right that in this simple example this is over-kill, but as soon as you start having complex data and state, this makes sense and becomes quite helpful.

Comment: Man that's complicated. I'll have to start off with the MVC model on a smaller project I think because it doesn't quite make sense for me here in this instance. But thank you though! Also, do you know why if I try to render the level and score from Game Panel where the Score Panel is, it won't show? Like, add 200 to the location on the x axis, `g.drawString("Level: " + level, this.getWidth()/2+200, this.getHeight()/2-200);` so that it will appear where the location of the Score Panel is... is it because the Score Panel is overlapping the Game Panel?

Comment: @Growler sorry it is a bit of over-kill, but as soon as your state gets complex, it can be quite helpful. For instance, if you're doing a Tetris program, then the model would hold the logical state of all of the pieces including the piece that's falling, and the GUI would listen to the model and render the changes to the pieces in its drawing.

Comment: @Growler because ScorePanel likely covers GamePanel there and ScorePanel is opaque.

Comment: Can I move the Score and Level that GamePanel renders to the foreground?

Comment: @Growler I would display the score and level information on ScorePanel. Keep these things separate. I would also display the info in JLabels or JTextFields rather than render them via paintComponent.

Answer (score 3):

You should separate your business logic from your presentation. Please read about: [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Comment: Comments are for requesting clarification from the author or leaving constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post. I believe this is an answer. ;)

Comment: I believe this to be a good answer and an excellent comment; just trying to help. :]

Comment: Sure, Stack Overflow is all about helping each others. :)